# Small error in Java CORDIC implementation using BigDecimals

Tags: java, algorithm, math, trigonometry, cordic

I implemented the CORDIC algorithm in Java, and for a first iteration I just took the example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC and rewrote it in Java.

But it seems my implementation does return sin and cos with a small error:
E.g. When calculating the sine of 1/3
intead of 
`0.32719469679615224417334408526762060` my implementation returns `0.3271946967961523696204423482988852` which is only correct up to 14 decimal places,  instead of 34 as defined in `MathContext.DECIMAL128`

so these tests fail:

```
BigDecimal oneThird = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(3, MathContext.DECIMAL128),MathContext.DECIMAL128);
BigDecimal tmp = Cordic.sin(oneThird, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
// tmp = 0.3271946967961523696204423482988852
assertEquals(0, new BigDecimal("0.32719469679615224417334408526762060").compareTo(tmp));

tmp = Cordic.cos(oneThird, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
// tmp = 0.9449569463147379497146525865916989
assertEquals(0, new BigDecimal("0.944956946314737664388284007675880609").compareTo(tmp));
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
package net.objecthunter.math;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.MathContext;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.PresentationDirection;

public class Cordic {
    // in GNU octae this table can be generated using the command
    // "printf("%.34f\n", cumprod(1./sqrt(1.+2.^-(2.*i))))"
    public static BigDecimal K[] = new BigDecimal[]{
            new BigDecimal("0.7071067811865474617150084668537602",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6324555320336757713306496953009628",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6135719910778962837838435007142834",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6088339125177524291387953780940734",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6076482562561682509993943313020281",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6073517701412960434481647098436952",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072776440935261366149688910809346",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072591122988928447057332959957421",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072544793325624912228022367344238",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072533210898752864537186724191997",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072530315291344571448917122324929",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529591389449477034645497042220",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529410413972650317759871541057",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529365170102888527026152587496",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529353859135170523586566559970",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529351031393796134238982631359",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350324458174981145930360071",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350147723992137116511003114",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350103540446426109156163875",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350092494837554113473743200",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350089733712891870709427167",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350089043154170553862059023",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350088871069601736962795258",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350088827770903776581690181",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350088816668673530330124777",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.6072529350088814448227481079811696",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128)};

    // In GNU octave this table is generated using this command:
    // printf("%.34f\n",atan(2.^-(0:40)))
    public static BigDecimal A[] = new BigDecimal[]{
            new BigDecimal("0.7853981633974482789994908671360463",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.4636476090008060935154787784995278",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.2449786631268641434733268624768243",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.1243549945467614381566789916178095",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0624188099959573500230547438150097",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0312398334302682774421544564802389",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0156237286204768312941615349132007",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0078123410601011111439873069173245",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0039062301319669717573901390750279",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0019531225164788187584341550007139",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0009765621895593194594364927496599",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0004882812111948982899262139412144",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0002441406201493617712447448120372",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0001220703118936702078530659454358",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000610351561742087725935014541623",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000305175781155260957271547345160",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000152587890613157615423778681873",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000076293945311019699810389967098",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000038146972656064961417507561819",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000019073486328101869647792853193",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000009536743164059608441276310632",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000004768371582030888422810640821",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000002384185791015579736676881098",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000001192092895507806808997385635",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000596046447753905522081060953",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000298023223876953025738326494",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000149011611938476545956387749",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000074505805969238281250000000",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000037252902984619140625000000",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000018626451492309570312500000",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000009313225746154785156250000",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000004656612873077392578125000",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000002328306436538696289062500",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000001164153218269348144531250",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000000582076609134674072265625",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000000291038304567337036132812",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000000145519152283668518066406",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000000072759576141834259033203",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000000036379788070917129516602",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000000018189894035458564758301",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128),
            new BigDecimal("0.0000000000009094947017729282379150",
                    MathContext.DECIMAL128)};

    public static BigDecimal[] apply(BigDecimal arg, MathContext mc) {
        // TODO: reduce the arg to 0 <= arg <= 2*pi

        if (arg.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            return new BigDecimal[]{BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ZERO};
        }

        if (arg.compareTo(new BigDecimal(Math.PI)) == 0) {
            return new BigDecimal[]{BigDecimal.ONE.negate(), BigDecimal.ZERO};
        }

        if (arg.compareTo(new BigDecimal(2 * Math.PI)) == 0) {
            return new BigDecimal[]{BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ZERO};
        }

        if (arg.compareTo(new BigDecimal(Math.PI / 2d)) == 0) {
            return new BigDecimal[]{BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ONE};
        }

        if (arg.compareTo(new BigDecimal(3d * Math.PI / 2d)) == 0) {
            return new BigDecimal[]{BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ONE.negate()};
        }

        int i = 0;
        BigDecimal beta = arg;
        BigDecimal sigma;
        BigDecimal factor;
        BigDecimal powerOfTwo = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal y = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        BigDecimal angle = A[0];
        BigDecimal two = BigDecimal.ONE.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
        BigDecimal precision = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE,
                mc.getPrecision() * 2);
        BigDecimal tmpx;
        BigDecimal tmpy;
        for (; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            if (beta.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
                sigma = BigDecimal.ONE.negate();
            } else {
                sigma = BigDecimal.ONE;
            }
            factor = sigma.multiply(powerOfTwo, mc);
            tmpx = x.subtract(y.multiply(factor, mc), mc);
            tmpy = y.add(x.multiply(factor, mc), mc);
            x = tmpx;
            y = tmpy;
            beta = beta.subtract(sigma.multiply(angle));
            powerOfTwo = powerOfTwo.divide(two, mc);
            if (i + 2 > A.length) {
                angle = angle.divide(two);
            } else {
                angle = A[i + 1];
            }
            if (beta.abs().compareTo(precision) < 0) {
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return new BigDecimal[]{x.multiply(K[Math.min(K.length - 1, i)], mc),
                y.multiply(K[Math.min(K.length - 1, i)], mc)};
    }

    public static BigDecimal cos(BigDecimal arg, MathContext mc) {
        return apply(arg, mc)[0];
    }

    public static BigDecimal sin(BigDecimal arg, MathContext mc) {
        return apply(arg, mc)[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Such things are approximations and will always have "error" - the more important question is if the error is more than *should be expected*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Right, The precision I want is 34 decimal places, that's why im using MathContext.DECIMAL128. And the size-of-error checking happens at the last "if" of the apply-method. But still it seems it's only correct up to 15 decimal places.

Comment: Your test code does not match the shown source code. In your test you use `Cordic.sin(oneThird)`, but your code only defines `public static BigDecimal sin(BigDecimal arg, MathContext mc) {` (with two arguments). The problem could be caused by the MathContext since that defines the precision if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @SebastianH: Yeah sorry I forgot to add the `MathContext.DECIMAL128` to the `sin()` call, since I removed a layer of indirection for this question. I fixed the question...

Comment: Using Math.PI as a source of the value of *pi* is probably unwise.  Instead use a published decimal value.

Comment: @HotLicks indeed but this is just a first iteration of the algo, a lot of stuff is till missing, like constant values for PI and e, also using bitshifts instead of division by 2, and normallizing the input value to 0<=arg<=2pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your atan values are wrong. Magma with higher precision tells me that the first entry should be

```
0.78539816339744830961566084581987572104929234984377645524373614807695410157155224
```

while in your table it is

```
0.7853981633974482789994908671360463
```

The full table from Magma is

```
0.78539816339744830961566084581987572104929234984377645524373614807695410157155224, 
0.4636476090008061162142562314612144020285370542861202638109330887201978641657417, 
0.24497866312686415417208248121127581091414409838118406712737591466735511958764209, 
0.12435499454676143503135484916387102557317019176980408991511411911572226742756675, 
0.06241880999595734847397911298550511360627388779749919460752781689869026721680345, 
0.03123983343026827625371174489249097703249566372540004025531558625579642101943244, 
0.01562372862047683080280152125657031891111413980090541788141050739666477417640177, 
0.00781234106010111129646339184219928162122281172501472355745390224838987204533523, 
0.00390623013196697182762866531142438714035749011520285621521309514901134416395438, 
0.00195312251647881868512148262507671393161074677723351033905753396043108530313709, 
0.00097656218955931943040343019971729085163419701581008759004900725226763752035508, 
0.00048828121119489827546923962564484866619236113313500303710940335348751213674327, 
0.00024414062014936176401672294325965998621241779097061761180790046091017847021746, 
0.00012207031189367020423905864611795630093082940901578749845193983784664259022045, 
6.1035156174208775021662569173829153785143536833346179337671134316586565776889807e-5, 
3.0517578115526096861825953438536019750949675119437837531021156883611630486111094e-5, 
1.525878906131576210723193581269788513742923814457587484624118640744586426707683e-5, 
7.629394531101970263388482340105090586350743918468077157763830696533368540109726e-6, 
3.814697265606496282923075616372993722805257303968866310187439250393888463610412e-6, 
1.907348632810187035365369305917244168714342165450153366670057723467064463709843e-6, 
9.53674316405960879420670689923112390019634124498790160133611802076003329888112e-7, 
4.7683715820308885992758382144924707587049404378664196740053215887142363814443e-7, 
2.3841857910155798249094797721893269783096898769063155913766911372217648282103e-7, 
1.19209289550780685311368497137922112645967587664586735576738225215437199588955e-7, 
5.9604644775390554413921062141788874250030195782366297314294565710005108461658e-8, 
2.9802322387695303676740132767709503349043907067445107249258477840843557260847e-8, 
1.4901161193847655147092516595963247108248930025964720012170057805491014206727e-8, 
7.4505805969238279871365645744953921132066925545665870075947601416173711836981947e-9, 
3.7252902984619140452670705718119235836719483287370405242319982692391073974358196e-9, 
1.8626451492309570290958838214764904345065282835738863513491050124951302594430928e-9, 
9.313225746154785153557354776845613038929264961492906739437685424219745532957262e-10, 
4.656612873077392577788419347105701629734786389156161742132349255441464969391566e-10, 
2.328306436538696289020427418388212703712742932049818605254866622806071463876315e-10, 
1.164153218269348144525990927298526587963964573800142900265849791708846857314265e-10, 
5.82076609134674072264967615912315823495491562577952724239762061671471623655995e-11, 
2.91038304567337036132730326989039477936936320036398304958299345250291480963431e-11, 
1.45519152283668518066395978373629934742117036089367107320672702133070941642532e-11, 
7.27595761418342590332018410467037418427646293888214296401117528908389857511e-12, 
3.6379788070917129516601402005837967730345578669779258118296083646485740987638e-12, 
1.8189894035458564758300761188229745966293197333602925371452076535033553005523e-12, 
9.0949470177292823791503881172787182457866496666966318622647928818549076982886781e-13
```

Or try it for yourself on (http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/):

```
RR:=RealField(80);
[ Arctan(RR!2^(-k)) : k in [0..40] ];
```

Comment: +1 Since the OP entered only 15 digits, it's not surprising that only 14 digits of accuracy are observed on output.

Comment: More significant than Magma's higher precision was it's higher accuracy.

Comment: Yes of course. The inner working accuracy in Magma operations is chosen so that all of the displayed digits are valid. Displaying 53 bit of working accuracy in 34 decimal digits still gives only 14 valid digits.

Comment: @rajah9 What do you mean by the OP only entered 15 digits?

Comment: @fas -- Only the first 15 digits or so are correct.  Presumably the numbers were produced by running code in an environment where the numeric precision is about that of an IEEE 64 bit float, yielding about 15 digits of precision.  Printing the numbers out to 34 digits added a false sense of confidence but nothing more.

Comment: @LutzL: I see! I was under the impression that setting the output_precision and output_max_field_witdh to appropriate values gave me the desired precision when generating these tables in GNU Octave but it seems I misinterpreted that. Thanks!

Comment: "Octave uses the C library trigonometric functions. It is expected that these functions are defined by the ISO/IEC 9899 Standard." [Octave documentation "Trigonometry"](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Trigonometry.html) So yes, 64 bit double format only.

Comment: Hint: Next time Google "trigonometric table high precision".

Comment: (Another thing to do is use whatever system you're using to calculate the arc-sine of 1, multiply times 2, and compare to published values of pi.)